# Filtering out similar value strings sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is how my data appears in one of the tables in my database

| id | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234-6+1 |
| 2 | 123461 |
| 3 | 023-FD-0 |
| 4 | 023FD0 |
| 5 | 5FD23FO |
| 6 | 5FD+23F+O |
| 7 | 12334 |

How can I achieve below in my select statement.

| id | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123461 | 1234-6+1 |
| 2 | 023FD0 | 023-FD-0 |
| 3 | 5FD23FO | 5FD+23F+O |

Have tried to use regex but in vain. A sample select query will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you tying to do this in SQL (MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server) or in another language (Python, JS, C#)?

Comment: i'm trying to do it in SQL @Brad

Comment: I don't understand where the values for the `id` column in the expected output come from? They don't appear to match the ID values of the original rows.

Comment: There are many sql variants with different possible answers and approaches. Do you know which sql variant you are using specifically?

Comment: the ids can be ignored in the expected output. my major concern is on the other column

Comment: postgresql is the variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self-`join`:

```
select distinct case when t1.column1 < t2.column1 then t1.column1 else t2.column1 end, 
    case when t2.column1 > t1.column1 then t2.column1 else t1.column1 end from t t1 
join t t2 
on regexp_replace(t1.column1, '\W', '', 'g') = regexp_replace(t2.column1, '\W', '', 'g') and t1.id != t2.id
```

Comment: thanks Ajax1234. this seems to work well where data values have spaces between the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you are looking to replace just the characters '-' and '+', you can use the replace function twice. Use a simple regular expression to identify the rows to process:

```
with test(id, column1) as 
     (values (1, '1234-6+1')
           , (2, '123461')
           , (3, '023-fd-0')
           , (4, '023fd0')
           , (5, '5fd23fo')
           , (6, '5fd+23f+o')
           , (7, '12334')
      )
select id
     , replace(replace(column1,'-',''),'+','') as column1
     , column1 as column2
  from test 
 where column1 ~ '(-|\+)';
```

Comment: thanks Belayer. your code gives me the expected output. Do you have any resource you would recommend me to read to have a clear understanding of your use of ~ '(-|\+)' regex and the replace() function.

Comment: Sorry, I typically include those references. The best reference for any built-in function or operation is the Documentation manual. In your case specifically [POSIX regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) and [String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html).

Comment: thanks Belayer. references was very helpful